# Disable scrolling on full width mobile menu + allow submenu to close after clicking parent <li> a second time

Tags: javascript, html, css, navigation

I created a custom navigation, which turns into a hamburger icon on smaller devices. When clicked, the icon expands a full-width menu, however the problem is that the user can still scroll down as if they're viewing my content, so there's essentially the option to pointlessly scroll, which I would like to disable. I also have a submenu under one of my links, and when you click the parent

, the drop-down submenu collapses. However, I'd like to make it so that on a subsequent click, the menu hides again, and make it so that the user can keep collapsing and hiding the menu upon clicks.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
// Using const for non-reassignable variables
const hamburger = document.getElementById('hamburger-custom');
const navMenu = document.getElementById('custom-nav-menu');
const closeButton = document.getElementById('mobile-close-icon');

if (!hamburger || !navMenu || !closeButton) {
    console.error('Critical elements for the navigation menu are missing!');
    return; // Stop the execution if the elements are not found
}

// Improved toggle function
function toggleMenu() {
    navMenu.classList.toggle('active'); // This single line replaces the whole if/else block

    // Managing ARIA-expanded attribute for better accessibility
    const isExpanded = navMenu.classList.contains('active');
    hamburger.setAttribute('aria-expanded', isExpanded);
    closeButton.setAttribute('aria-expanded', isExpanded);

    // Handling the close icon display state without relying on pointerEvents
    const closeIconWrapper = document.getElementById('mobile-close-icon-wrapper');
    if (closeIconWrapper) {
        closeIconWrapper.style.display = isExpanded ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

// Event listeners
hamburger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
closeButton.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);

// Optionally: Listen for the 'Esc' key to close the menu
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.key === 'Escape' && navMenu.classList.contains('active')) {
        toggleMenu();
    }
});
});
```

```css
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu a span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu a span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 0.4s;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu a:hover span::after {
  visibility: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .submenu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  }

.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .has-submenu:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
}
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .submenu li a {
  padding: 10px 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.has-submenu > a:after {
content: "▼";
font-size: 10px;
margin-left: 5px;
}
#hamburger-custom {
display: none;
}

/* Media query for smaller screens (max-width: 1024px) */
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
#hamburger-custom {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30px;
    height: 25px;
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

#hamburger-custom:focus {
    outline: none;
}

#hamburger-custom .bar {
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu {
    position: fixed; /* Fixed positioning to cover the entire viewport */
    top: 0;
    left: -100%; /* Start off screen left */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh; /* Full height of the viewport */
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; /* Center the content vertically */
    list-style: none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
    z-index: 1000; /* High z-index to stay on top of other elements */
    transition: left 0.3s ease;
}

.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu.active {
    left: 0; 
}
  
.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu li a {
    text-align: center; /* Center the link text */
    padding: 15px; /* Add some padding */
    display: block; /* Make links take up the whole line */
}

.vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .has-submenu .submenu {
  display:none;
 position: absolute; /* Already there, keeps the submenu out of the document flow */
    top: 100%; /* Changed from '50px' to make it appear right below the parent menu item */
    left: 0; /* Changed from '60%' to align with the left edge of the parent menu item */
    width: 100%; /* Add this to ensure submenu takes full width of parent */
    box-shadow: none; /* Optional: in case you don't want box shadow effect */
    z-index: 1000; /* Optional: to ensure the submenu appears above other elements */
    background-color: #fff; /* Already there, for a white background */
}
  
  


#mobile-close-icon-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1002;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px;
}
  
.custom-nav-menu.active + #mobile-close-icon-wrapper {
    display: block;
}
.mobile-close-icon {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
#mobile-close-icon-wrapper {
    display: none !important;}
}
```

```html
<nav class="vassil-main-navigation">
<!-- Hamburger button -->
<button class="hamburger-custom" id="hamburger-custom">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
</button>
<!-- Navigation Menu -->
<ul class="custom-nav-menu" id="custom-nav-menu">
    <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/about-us/"><span>About Us</span> </a></li>
    <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/kitchen-remodeling/"><span>Kitchen Remodeling</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/bathroom-remodeling/"><span>Bathroom Remodeling</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/complete-remodeling/"><span>Complete Remodeling</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/gallery/"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://houniqueconstruction.com/contact/"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
</ul>
<!-- 'X' button to close the fullscreen menu -->
<div id="mobile-close-icon-wrapper">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobile-close-icon" id="mobile-close-icon">&times;</a>
</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved toggle function for Disable scrolling on full width mobile menu

```
function toggleMenu() {
    // Add or remove overflow: hidden to the body
    const body = document.body;
    if (isExpanded) {
        body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    } else {
        body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
}
```

add allow submenu to close after clicking parent `<li>` a second time

```
 // remove for if you set with event    
     .vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .has-submenu:hover .submenu {
                  display: block;
    }
 // add for active class for toggle event
     .vassil-main-navigation .custom-nav-menu .has-submenu.active .submenu {
          display: block;
     }
```

add js

```
// Get the "Services" link and its submenu
const servicesLink = document.querySelector('.has-submenu');
const submenu = servicesLink.querySelector('.submenu');

// Add event listeners to handle click and mouse enter/leave
servicesLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the link from navigating

  // Toggle the 'active' class to control submenu display
  servicesLink.classList.toggle('active');

  if (servicesLink.classList.contains('active')) {
    submenu.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    submenu.style.display = 'none';
  }
});

servicesLink.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  if (!servicesLink.classList.contains('active')) {
    servicesLink.classList.add('active');
    submenu.style.display = 'block';
  }
});

servicesLink.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  if (servicesLink.classList.contains('active')) {
    servicesLink.classList.remove('active');
    submenu.style.display = 'none';
  }
});
```